# Instructions to make combat a combat encounter with a Chimera more interesting

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, gm-techniques, encounter-design

I'm looking for tips for creatures or obstacles that could spice up an encounter.

Background:
The battle's purpose is to be an entrance test for the organization the campaign is centered around. The party consists of 5 fifth level characters (with multiple healers), and I was thinking that the battle could be centered around a Chimera. But not only would it be boring with only a Chimera it would also be too easy (the battle takes place in a colosseum/arena type environment located on the outskirts of a big city).

Are there any instructions in the published books to make interesting additions to combat encounters, such as a) making the combat fit a specific location thematically, b) mixing different kinds of monsters, or c) adding traps and other interactive things to the battleground?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the answers to https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69528/how-can-i-make-combat-more-tactically-interesting-for-me-as-a-dm?